# How to test javascript redirection without redirecting?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine for some testing, although this can be generally applied to browser-based javascript unit testing.

I have a function that, on certain conditions redirects the user to a different page using `window.location.assign`.  The problem is, if this line is reached, the page is redirected.  In this case, since it's redirected to `'/'`, the page reloads, and all the tests run again.  What can I do to test that the function reaches the line where it redirects, *without redirecting*?

Comment: can you modify the page source?

Comment: modifying the page source would make the unit testing incredibly intrusive.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have faced this same problem. My solution was to break out the actual redirect into a single purpose function. That is, don't do any condition checking or other logic, just redirect.
Say this is the old code...

```
function redirect() {
 if(something) {
  window.location = "/";
 else if(somethingElse)
  window.location = "/?a=42";
 else
  window.location = "/derp";
}
```

I would change that to..

```
function redirect() {
 if(something) {
  doRedirect("/");
 else if(somethingElse)
  doRedirect("/?a=42");
 else
  doRedirect("/derp");
}

function doRedirect(href) {
 window.location = href;
}
```

Then you can `spyOn` the `doRedirect` function to ensure the redirect function is passing in the correct URI for the conditions.

Comment: I would prefer a method that wouldn't involve changing my JS code.  Unfortunately, I may have no choice.

Comment: Fortunately that is a fairly trivial change, I have long wanted a better solution as well but that is the only thing I've come up with.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty here is that your code depends on a global variable, `window`, so you can't easily replace that dependency in your test. Here's the basic idea of what I did in a similar situation. Write your code so that `window` is only ever accessed indirectly, except during initialization where it gets saved off into a local / instance variable.

```
var unit = {
  initialize: function () {
    this.window = window;
  },
  codeThatRedirects: function (newUrl) {
    this.window.location.href = newUrl;
  }
};
```

Now you can replace `unit.window` with something else, maybe like this:

```
unit.initialize();
unit.window = {
  location: {
    href: "dummy"
  }
};

unit.codeThatRedirects('http://new.url.com');

assert(unit.window.location.href === "http://new.url.com");
```

Comment: You're going to notice some very odd behaviour if you try to redefine window in a browser-run test. It's not an actual variable.

Comment: This code is not redefining window. It merely redefines a variable that used to contain a reference to window, so that it now contains a reference to another object instead.

Comment: I realize what you're trying to do, yes.  But try to actually do it.  Open up the developer console and try it.  You'll be surprised.  For example, in Chrome, it will ignore your attempt to reassign it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting that behavior. Which assignment are you saying fails? I just tried it in the Chrome developer console and it behaved as expected. Copy and paste the code into the developer console, but replace the last statement with `unit.window.location.href === "http://new.url.com"` (since `assert` is fake). It should return true.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example for testing that clicking a purchase button redirects the user to an outside URL using the method @Morgan mentioned.

```
# navigation.coffee
exports.goToExternalUrl = (url) ->
    window.location = url


# myView.coffee
Navigation = require("lib/navigation")

exports.MyView = Backbone.View.extend
  events:
    "click .purchase":"purchase"

  purchase: ->
    Navigation.goToExternalUrl("http://amazon.com/someproduct")


# my_view_spec.coffee
Navigation = require("lib/navigation")
MyView = require("myView").MyView

describe("MyView"), ->
  it "can be purchased", ->
    # this line prevents the location.href from actually being set
    spyOn(Navigation,'goToExternalUrl').andCallFake (->)

    $el.find('.purchase').trigger('click')
    expect(Navigation.goToExternalUrl).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using GreaseMonkey to update the javascript, but this remains somewhat intrusive...